# MVC3 inject html content into a loaded view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to MVC3 and I have problem trying to render html content into a view that has already been rendered.
I have a view with 2 divs, left column and right column. The left column renders a listview when the view loads the first time. I want to change the html content loaded on the right column based on the item clicked in the listview on the left. I am using jquery mobile.

When I click an item in the column on the left I want to load a view on the right.

Comment: Your question contains a high amount of the words `I want` and nowhere to be seen the words `Here's the code I have tried` and `here's the error message I got` and `here's the problem I am experiencing with my code`, ... I think you get the point => nobody is going to do your job. Stack Overflow is not an outsourcing company. Go read documentations. Go try things. And if you encounter some specific programming related problem don't hesitate to come back here, show your progress, and ask a real question.

Answer (score 0):

At server side you need to create an action, that returns html for the right column (simple ViewResult).

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult RightColumn()
{
    return View("right");
}
```

At client side you can use jQuery load() function to call this action and insert result into right column container:

```
$("#left-column-button").click(function () {
    $("#right-column").load("/right");
});
```